# Solr Facet Functions and Analytics

Tags: solr, lucene, faceted-search

I have found the interesting article on [Solr Facet Functions](http://heliosearch.org/solr-facet-functions/) available in heliosearch.

I am just wondering if the same is available in native solr?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That kind of functionality will come with SOLR 5.1. Yonik, the developer of Heliosearch, joined a big SOLR company. Development on Heliosearch will not continue, but Yonik is porting the changes to SOLR. See the following thread for details:

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/heliosearch/ji466TddEDY

Answer (score 0):

I don't think here are facet/aggregate functions like that. The closest thing I've found is the stats component:

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/The+Stats+Component

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Faceting#Faceting-CombiningStatsComponentWithPivots